# How to get text from the tag without children tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For example: there are two div blocks, div2 inside div1. I need to get content from div1, exclude content from div2 using bs4

my code:

```
<div>
    <div id=1>Text 1
        <div id=2> Text 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

expected output:
`Text 1`

Comment: _my code:_ What programming language code is this?)) Did you try writing python script with bs4 (looked it up from your tags, so I guess you know the tool) at least?

Comment: Is it possible in your use case to have multiple pieces of text within a div?

Comment: @sudden_appearance 'my code' means html code which i'm trying to parse. idk why u acting so fool, i think everybody understand what i'm asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative, you could use [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings) and select by `index`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div>
    <div id=1>Text 1
        <div id=2> Text 2</div>
    </div>
</div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

list(soup.find('div', {'id': '1'}).stripped_strings)[0]
```

###### Output

```
Text 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''
<div>
    <div id=1>Text 1
        <div id=2> Text 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
result = soup.find('div', {'id': '1'}) \
             .findAll(text=True, recursive=False)[0] \
             .strip()
```

This is the result:

```
>>> result
'Text 1'
```